# Unity Error: "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed" with an own save and load system

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, load

### The problem

Hi, I am having a problem: when I use the **LoadParty** method, which use the **JsonUltility** on a for loop, It just drop an error:

> "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed"

The for loop travel along a class called Player, which has all the stats of the player. So I think maybe the problem has to do with that.

### What I tried

I have tried to make changes on the for loop, so the program can deserialize the data, but I could not camed with a solution.

### Code

Full code of the Class Save and Load System:

```
public void SaveParty(Player[] players, string nameFile)
{
    Debug.Log("Saving!");
    FileStream file = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + nameFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

    try
    {
        // Binary Formatter
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        // Serialize
        for(int x = 0; x < players.Length; x++)
        {
            var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(players[x]);
            formatter.Serialize(file, json);
        }
    }
    catch (SerializationException e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error Saving: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        file.Close();
        Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);
    }
}

// Save Current Party Data
public void SaveCurrentParty()
{
    // If exist will delete, and save again
    if(FirstTimeSaving)
    {
        File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + NameFile[1]);
        SaveParty(gameManager.CurrentParty, NameFile[1]);
    }
    // If not exist will save
    if(!FirstTimeSaving)
    {
        SaveParty(gameManager.CurrentParty, NameFile[1]);
        FirstTimeSaving = true;
    }
}

// Load Party Data
public void LoadParty(Player[] party, string nameFile)
{
    Debug.Log("Loading!");
    FileStream file = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + nameFile, FileMode.Open);
    
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        // Error Here ↓
        for(int i = 0; i < party.Length; i++)
        {
            JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite((string)formatter.Deserialize(file), party[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (SerializationException e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error Load: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Full code of the player class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Stats
    public int Hp;
    public int Sp;
    public int level;
    public int St;
    public int Ma;
    public int Ag;
    public int En;
    public int Lu;

    // Items
    public MeleeWeapon Weapon;

    // Skills
    public List<Skills> skills = new List<Skills>();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what does your file content look like?

Comment: At the moment, like is ÿÿÿÿ »{"Hp":25,"Sp":20,"level":1,"St":2,"Ma":0,"Ag":2,"En":2,"Lu":3,"Weapon":{"instanceID":18578},"skills":[{"instanceID":18608},{"instanceID":16468},{"instanceID":18610},{"instanceID":16468}]} ÿÿÿÿ »{"Hp":20,"Sp":25,"level":1,"St":4,"Ma":2,"Ag":5,"En":3,"Lu":4,"Weapon":{"instanceID":18578},"skills":[{"instanceID":18608},{"instanceID":16468},{"instanceID":18610},{"instanceID":16468}]} Keep in mind, the file is totally dynamic, it can change in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Scott Hannen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164866/7111561)

In general [**Don't use BinaryFormatter anymore at all!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) .. and in your case here you already **have** a serialized JSON `string` ... Why using a `BinaryFormatter` on it at all?

First of all I would create a proper data container class for the player like

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerStats
{
    public int Hp;
    public int Sp;
    public int level;
    public int St;
    public int Ma;
    public int Ag;
    public int En;
    public int Lu;
    
    // Assuming here that both MeleeWepaon and Skills are Serializable types
    public MeleeWeapon Weapon;

    // Skills
    public List<Skills> skills = new List<Skills>();
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerStats Stats;
}
```

**Why?** -> Because it is not allowed to create `MonoBehaviour` instances by deserializing from JSON which is what we are going to do further below ;)

And then simply use a wrapper class like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

[Serializable]
public class PlayersData
{ 
    public PlayerStats[] Data; 

    // Empty constructor is needed by serializer
    public PlayersData(){}

    public PlayersData(IEnumerable<Player> data)
    {
        Data = data.Select(p => p.Stats).ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Why?** -> The built-in `JsonUtility` doesn't support the direct (de)serialization of array/list types.

So serialize this type instead and simply directly write the resulting JSON string into the file like e.g.

```
public void SaveParty(Player[] players, string nameFile)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, nameFile);
    Debug.Log($"Saving!");
          
    try
    {
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(new PlayersData (players));
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        Debug.Log($"Saved to \"{path}\n"); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"{e.GetType} while saving: {e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

And for loading just go the other way round, simply load the entire content and deserilialize it into the wrapper container class in one go. Then assign the data to according player instances

```
public void LoadParty(Player[] party, string nameFile)
{
    Debug.Log("Loading!");
    var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, nameFile);
    
    try
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
        
        var data = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayersData>(JSON);
        for(var i = 0; i < Mathf.Min(data.Length, party.Length); i++)
        {
            party[i].Stats = data.Data[i];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"{e.GetType} while loading: {e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

---

Hint: If your `Player` has any `[SerializeField] private ...` fields that you want to (de)serialize as well then you'd rather have to implement a setter method in the `Player` taking the `PlayerStats` parameter and assign them "manually" accordingly

Comment: Check in LoadParty, the var data isn´t Treated as an array!, any ideas?

Comment: @Sfoyarbide fixed that .. it should be `data.Data[i]` .. maybe not the best naming I came up with  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to read from the same `FileStream` repeatedly in a loop. The first operation reads the file and the advances the position to the end of the stream. After that the exception is thrown because there's nothing left in the stream to read.

That happens here - it has nothing to do with `JsonUtility`:

```
(string)formatter.Deserialize(file)
```

That reads the whole stream to the end.

This isn't an issue when you're writing because with each object you serialize you're appending to the stream.

One solution is to serialize and deserialize the entire `Player[]`. That way you only read from the stream once. When you open the file you're at position 0 - the beginning of the stream. You read the entire file and deserialize `Player[]`, not individual `Player` objects. When it's done you've read the entire stream and you have all of your data.

I'm sidestepping concerns about whether to even use binary serialization. The underlying principle applies regardless of how data is serialized.

Comment: In general [**You should not used `BinaryFormatter` anymore at all!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) .. here it also makes no sense since the data is already serialized via JSON anyway (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165311/7111561)) ;)